# Custom menu in TFS web access (TFS 15)

Tags: tfs

I tried these steps and i created a sample extension similar to this site  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/get-started/node .

But i need to pass parameter to the site which i am opening using this new extension. Is it possible ?

Parameters like : project name , environment(TFS URL) where the TFS is running.

And i am facing an error when trying to open a page in an MVC application hosted on IIS internally, the application uses Durandal ,Knockout and HTML 5 for the UI.

Not able attach the screen shot pasting the part of new extension script

```
   "icons": {

     },
    "contributions": [
        {
            "id": "Fabrikam.HelloWorld",
            "type": "ms.vss-web.hub",
            "description": "Adds a 'Hello' hub to the Work hub group.",
            "targets": [
                "ms.vss-work-web.work-hub-group"
                ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "Hello Testing",
                "order": 99,
                "uri": "http://test-server/AdminConsole2015Beta/#/tfsreports/boc_projects/ALM/alm-beta-app1/0"
            }
        }
    ],
    "scopes": [
        "vso.work"
    ],
    "files": [
        {
            "path": "tfsReports.html", "addressable": true
        },
        {
            "path": "scripts", "addressable": true
        },
        {
            "path": "sdk/scripts", "addressable": true
        }

    ]
}
```

In the above script i want to open the URL in the URI property which opens the page tfsreports.html  after routing using durandal. Is that possible here? See screen shot for refrence[image: Extension jason script]

Comment: What's your detail mean of `pass parameter to the site`? Did you only want to show the project name and  environment(TFS URL) where the TFS is running in your html page? Or something else?

Comment: What's the type of the extension you are creating? The code you provided is creating a custom hub but in the title you mentioned custom menu. And do you want to show the site in TFS web portal or open a new tab in browser? It is possible to get the parameter you want like project name, TFS Url, but how do you pass them to your site? Via URL parameters?

Comment: Sorry i am creating a custom hub not menu. And i would like to pass the parameter like this  http://alm-test-test:8080/AdminConsole2015Beta/#/tfsreports/boc_projects/{Project Name}/{TFS Url}

Answer (score 0):

Update your extension to below:

1. In the manifest file, update the "uri" of the "contributions" to "tfsReports.html".

```html
            "properties": {
                "name": "Hello Testing",
                "order": 99,
                "uri": "tfsReports.html"
            }
```

2. Add followings content in "tfsReports.html":

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
     <title>Hello World</title>
     <script src="sdk/scripts/VSS.SDK.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <script type="text/javascript">VSS.init();</script>
     <h1>Hello World</h1>
     <script type="text/javascript">
    VSS.init();
    VSS.ready(function () {
        var webContext = VSS.getWebContext();
        var projectname = webContext.project.name;
 var TFSUrl = webContext.collection.uri;
        var reportFrame = document.getElementById("reportFrame");
 var finalurl = "http://test-server/AdminConsole2015Beta/#/tfsreports/boc_projects/ALM/alm-beta-app1/0/" + projectname + "/" + TFSUrl;
 reportFrame.src = finalurl;
        VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();
    });
</script>
<div id="tfsreport">
    <iframe id="reportFrame" style="width:100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply it is working now . But how to add a Hub Group ?? I  referred this link https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-hub-group . But it is not working.

Comment: @shishirsasal Following the link you provided should work. What's the detailed issue you have when add a hub group?

Comment: It worked thank you. I was giving a different target in the manifest file

Comment: @shishirsasal Can you mark it as answer if it works? :)